# Immutable arrays after upgrading angular to 11

Tags: angular11, typescript4.0

I just upgraded Angular from 6 to 11 and also typescript to 4.1.5.
I have problems with changing properties of any object from an array. It results with an error

```
core.js:6150 ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'active' of object '[object Object]'
```

The object I'm trying to change is:

```
  export interface Agreement {
    active: boolean;
    ...
}
```

Also when I try to add something to any list, I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property 4, object is not extensible
at Array.push (<anonymous>)
```

Am I missing any global config property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply created a copy of given field like this:

`field = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(field))`